# How can I use the single field of the queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I would like to pick the value of "titolo", for example, from the query set. This is my code:

```
class PostUserListView(generic.DetailView):
    model=Autore
    template_name=('blogv1/post_list.html')
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        
        articolo=Articolo.objects.filter(autore__id=context['autore'].id)
```

The articolo is
<QuerySet [<Articolo: Ingegneria>]>

Models.py Articolo has 3 fields: Titolo (charField),Autore(foreign key) and DataPubblicazione (date field)

I'd like to take the value "titolo" from the articolo "ingegneria"

Comment: Share the `Articolo` model...

Answer (score 0):

all what you want, the values_list method of the queryset.

in your case:

```
articolo_pliral=Articolo.objects.filter(autore__id=context['autore'].id).values_list('titolo', flat=True)

single_articolo = articolo_pliral[0] if articolo_pliral.exist() else ''
```

PLease read more about Django.orm. The Answers on this question exists in documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list